# JavaScript - Adding user input text field to a th/td element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem definition**

I am trying to add a new feature in an old JS application. Specifically, I am trying to include a user input textbox that interacts with the other columns.

**Current design**

[image]

```
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.className = "antal";
    var text = document.createTextNode("Antal");
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);

    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.className = "Timer";
    var text = document.createTextNode("Timer");
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);

    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.className = "antal";
    th.id = "digit_fast_header"
    var text = document.createTextNode("Fastansatte");
    th.appendChild(text);
    th.style.display = "none";
    row.appendChild(th);
```

**My goal**
To add 1 more column named eksInput which should contain/generate td elements with user input

**EDIT**

I was looking through documentation for user input on w3schools, and my attempt is the following, though it doesn't follow the design of any of the other columns, and doesn't work.

**Edit 2**

I tried including the following:

```
var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "input";
th.id = "input_cont";
th.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='inpt_text' name='inpt[]' >";
row.appendChild(th);
```

Problem with this code is it makes the th element a user input text field, not the generated td elements.

**SOLVED**

My problem was solved by doing the following:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.className = "inputTest";
    td.id = "input_test" 
    td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='inpt_text' name = 'inpt[]' >";
    tr.appendChild(td);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How does your html look like?

Comment: What do you mean by interact with other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "input";
th.id = "input_cont";
th.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='inpt_text' name='inpt[]' >";
row.appendChild(th);
```

i think this code will help you...

Comment: IMHO you should have used `document.createElement()` also for the `<input type="text" ...` instead of using `th.innerHTML`.

Comment: @JSSGOD1337 show complete table html and js code so we can help